# RAZOR SQL. Use value from selected text and add that variable to the next query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, razor

I am trying to take the value of the selected text from a listbox:

```
    var db = Database.Open("localdb");
    var listRegion = "SELECT NameRegion,IdRegion FROM OfficesRegions ORDER BY NameRegion";

    List<SelectListItem> Regiondropdownlistdata = new List<SelectListItem>();
    bool isSelected = false;
    foreach (var item in db.Query(listRegion)){
    Regiondropdownlistdata.Add(new SelectListItem 
    {
        Value = item.IdRegion.ToString(),
        Text = item.NameRegion,
        Selected = isSelected
    });
    }
Regiondropdownlistdata.Add(new SelectListItem {Text = "Select Region",Value = "0", Selected = true });
```

and add that value to my query below to automatically pull the associated stores:

```
    var listoffice = "SELECT OfficeName,IdRegion FROM Offices WHERE IdRegion = @0 ORDER BY OfficeName";

List<SelectListItem> Officedropdownlistdata = new List<SelectListItem>();
bool selected = true;
foreach (var office in db.Query(listoffice)){
    Officedropdownlistdata.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = office.IdRegion.ToString(),
        Text = office.OfficeName,
        Selected = selected
    });
}
```

I am new to this so any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I would use parameterized sql or a stored procedure to avoid the sql injection attacks

Comment: Ok, so I used a parameterized SQL statement but I am still unsure how to pull the value of the selected region. Essentially I need to get    Value = office.IdRegion.ToString(),   and put that value to           var regionId = SelectListItem.value;
    var office = "SELECT OfficeName FROM Offices WHERE IdRegion =     @0";
    db.Execute(office,regionId);
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: office);                                                       I also need to learn how to properly format my comments so it looks better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BAD** Because it is open to sql injections

`String.Format("SELECT OfficeName,IdRegion FROM Offices WHERE IdRegion = {0} ORDER BY OfficeName", SomeStringVlaue);`

**BETTER**

```
 string esqlQuery =
    @"SELECT OfficeName,IdRegion FROM Offices WHERE IdRegion = @Target ORDER BY OfficeName";

    using (EntityCommand cmd = new EntityCommand(esqlQuery, conn))
    {
    // Create two parameters and add them to
    // the EntityCommand's Parameters collection
    EntityParameter param1 = new EntityParameter();
    param1.ParameterName = "target";
    param1.Value = "Cool Parameters";

    cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
    .....
```

[Parameterized EF Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738684%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: ... and this answers his question how?

Comment: this lets him add a dynamic string to a query he wants to use. Which is the question he asked. I also noted he was just going to use string concat which is bad so i gave him a better way of doing.

Comment: @gh9 Thanks for the quick reply. I do not see how I can pull the value  (ID) of the selected region and add that to my second query. Any further assistance it greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user3246109 do you have the selected value at query execution time? if you do just add it as a parameter to the sql query like my better example. If you are still having trouble upload your and we can look at it together